# ld doesn't find library file even if it is in the same folder

Tags: c++, macos, g++, ld

For testing purposes, I am trying to link a library to a simple hello world.

Here is the build command:

`g++ -ohello -I. -L. -llibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0 hello.cpp`

And this is the content of the working directory:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 rodolfo  wheel        97  8 Feb 01:15 hello.cpp
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel  42353984 23 Gen 17:58 libtensorflow_framework.2.15.0.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel     65647 23 Gen 14:42 libtensorflow_framework.2.15.0.dylib-2.params
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel        36 23 Gen 17:58 libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib -> libtensorflow_framework.2.15.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel        31 23 Gen 17:58 libtensorflow_framework.dylib -> libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel        33 23 Gen 17:58 libtensorflow_framework.so.2 -> libtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel  42353984 23 Gen 17:58 libtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rodolfo  wheel     65641 23 Gen 14:35 libtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0-2.params
```

Even if the library file exists and it is located in the same folder, here is the error returned by `g++`:

```
ld: library not found for -llibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why does `g++` not find the library file, even if it is located in the same folder and I have also added the current folder in the list of folders for the linking? I am running macOS Catalina v.10.15.7.

Answer (score 0):

According to the g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 user manual (which is not the same as what you are using, but the -l option is reasonably generic):

> -llibrary
>
> -l library
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your linker documentation for exact details.

In turn, the user manual entry for the GNU loader version 2.40-13.fc39 (again not the same as what you are using, but reasonably generic) states that:

> -l namespec
>
> --library=namespec
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld will search a directory for a library called libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a. (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.) Note that this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a file called filename.

The short answer is that g++ does not find the library file because you have not included `:` in the `-l` option and there is no file called either `liblibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0.so` or `liblibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0.a` in any of the library directories.

Here are my recommendations:

**Plan A**

Change `-llibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0` to `-l:libtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0`

**Plan B**

Do not include `lib` in the library name.  Change `-llibtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0` to `-ltensorflow_framework` and create a link in the local directory from `libtensorflow_framework.so` to `libtensorflow_framework.so.2.15.0`

**Plan C** (can be used in conjunction with Plans A and B)

Whereas `-I.` and `-L.` can be somewhat dangerous.  `-L.` especially is passed to the linker and by that time `.` may not refer to the same directory.  You could try changing `-I.` and `-L.` to `` -I`pwd` `` and `` -L`pwd` ``

Comment: I've never had any problems with relative paths in `-I` and `-L`.

Comment: Plan B seems to work without creating the additional link, probably because `libtensorflow.dylib` is pointed in this case. Trying to understand the difference between the two files and if the link you suggested is better.